# need help for installation of a extension WebP Optimized Images

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer

I want install an extension:
Magento 2

Open Source (CE)

WebP Optimized Images

Component name:
jajuma/module-webpimages

Versions: 2.1.8

### and tried to install with the installation sheet:

### https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/install/

I have the following questions:
When I do point 2 I will get the following message:

<oshopat01@vm30:/www$ bin/magento maintenance:enable
bash: agoshopat01@vm30:/www$: No such file or directory
<op.at$ bash: bin/magento: No such file or directory
bash: bash:: command not found

How can start point 4 to 6?
4. Update the composer.json file in your Magento project with the name and version of the extension.
5. Verify that the extension installed properly.
6. Enable and configure the extension.

- Update your composer.json file:
  is it correct that I must insert in the file composer.json at "require": the following:
  jajuma/module-webpimages:2.1.8

Here my composer.json file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hsv8xs3wb4t49up/composer.json?dl=0

Must I start the command on the Server?
composer require jajuma/module-webpimages:2.1.8

Where must I insert the public und private Key ?

Which command must I use and activate instead bin/magento module:status J2t_Payplug.

For the registration and compiling I think I must use the same command linke in the guide?
bin/magento setup:upgrade
and
bin/magento setup:upgrade

Hope someone can help me there
kindly regards

Answer (score 0):

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

And like that add php in all commands..
Not required only when execute composer commnad

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So you mean I should need only to start

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

That's all or what must I do next.
Kindly regards

Comment: I have done now the upgrade.
What are the next steps.
Hope someone can still help me there.
kindly regards

Comment: I want ask if someone can still help me here.
Kindly regards

Answer (score 0):

I have done the upgrade on my website and want ask again if I can do now the instruction from:
https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/install/

I am a bit carefully because I am not so familiar with magento2.
Hope someone can still help me here.
kindly regards for any answer